# UIButton Not Working inside UItableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uitableview, uibutton

I have a view consisting of a label and two buttons, which I named `UIView *footerView`, as I am implementing this in the last section of my table view. I have this view become the view for `indexPath.section = 3` by using `[cell.contentView addSubview: footerView]`

**This is my Problem:**

I can see the view inside the cell. But I cannot tap the buttons, as the cell gets selected instead of the buttons (which are inside the cells).

How do I get over this problem? ***My buttons are not even selectable!***

Here's the code... In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if (section == 3){

    cell = nil;
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if (indexPath.row ==0){

        cell.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.footerView];

    }

}
```

And the Footer view (in case anyone needs to see this):

```
 UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 3, 300, 44)];
textView.text = @"Terms and Conditions: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con- sectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut";

textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

[self.footerView addSubview:textView];

//create the button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 300, 44)];

//set title, font size and font color
[button setTitle:@"Create Account" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
// [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//set action of the button
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(createAccount:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setEnabled:YES];
//add the button to the view
[self.footerView addSubview:button];


UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 107, 300, 44)];

//set title, font size and font color
[cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
// [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//set action of the button
[cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelPressed:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[cancelButton setEnabled:YES];
//add the button to the view
[self.footerView addSubview:cancelButton];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to implement something similar to this

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (3 == indexPath.section){
      return nil;
    }
    return indexPath;
}
```

Ok so if I implement the above it works fine. I believe I can reproduce your issue by making the `UIButton` frame fall outside the cell's `contentView`. Make sure the cell is big enough to contain your label and it should function correctly. To make the cell larger to fit your content you may have to implement:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return aHeightThatIsBigEnoughToContainMySubViews;
}
```

Comment: @paul: I already took care of the height problem as well. It's bigger than my subviews for that section. The problem remains unsolved.

Comment: What is the frame for your `footerView` set as?

Comment: FML. Thanks man. Actually i had used ... `self.footerView  = [[UIView alloc] init`.. changed it to ... `self.footerView  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 150)];` Did the trick.

Comment: @Paul and @Deepak: I will now post a new question an a really serious problem I am facing, which is related to this question. Please help me out if possible ! I shall post in the next 10 minutes.

Comment: If you are not using ARC and you synthesized your `footerview` property that will cause a memory leak.

Comment: This is working fine for plain styled table views, however, in grouped style table views the button is not tappable. Any tips?