# Objective C: UITable Method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" does not work if label is added to cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel, didselectrowatindexpath

In my implementation, I had to add a custom label to the cell. However, I realize that by doing so, the cell area that is covered by the custom label will not react to the user's 'click' and hence will not trigger the method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".

```
CustomOHAttributLabel *questionLabel = [[CustomOHAttributLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, (60-labelHeight)/2, 280, labelHeight)];        

[cell.contentView addSubview:questionLabel];
```

Is there a way to allow the whole cell area to be responsive to the user's touch even after adding a Custom label to it?

Comment: Why can't you use a smaller label ? :O  and why don't you use cell.textLabel instead of a custom label ?

Comment: @Legolas, I need to change the color and bold some parts of the text. From my understanding I can't do that directly in the textLabel but need to add a custom label to it. Am I right to say that?

Comment: This looks like it might resolve it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669027/uibutton-not-working-inside-uitableviewcell

Comment: I add labels to cells all the time and this has never been an issue for me. Sounds like you are somehow blocking the touch event, and I suspect your custom label class is at fault in some way. Care to post the relevant initialization code? Is your custom label class inheriting from UILabel or did you subclass directly from UIView or UIResponder? If the latter, you will need to change some settings in order to mimic the UILabel default behavior(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a custom button and put that over the lavel and onClick call the same code, see this

```
CustomOHAttributLabel *questionLabel = [[CustomOHAttributLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, (60-labelHeight)/2, 280, labelHeight)];

UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame=CGRectMake(10, (60-labelHeight)/2, 280, labelHeight);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomeThing) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView addSubview:questionLabel];
[cell.contentView addSubview:btn];



-(void)doSomeThing
{
  //write code which you write in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [self doSomeThing];
}
```

Comment: Will this button cover up the label or is it a transparent button?

Comment: It is transparent button.UIButtonTypeCustom